# How do I open file in root node wirh mpi4py?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I have problem with writing a code to read file with mpi4py. I thought it's same with normal IO in python, so I tried

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
if rank == 0: #root node
    fh = MPI.File.Open(comm, "path_to_the_file\abc.json", "r")
```

But this code gives me error that the "r"(mode) part should be an integer.

I searched on the internet to get information about this but there was no information about this. I'm new to this stuff so please help me to open the file . If there's any other thing I'm doing wrong please advise me as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to mimic the C bindings ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify file opening mode using `MPI.MODE_RDONLY` to specify the file read only mode. If you want you can use Other modes `MPI.MODE_WRONLY, MPI.MODE_CREATE`

```py
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
mode = MPI_MODE_RDONLY
if rank == 0: #root node
    fh = MPI.File.Open(comm, "path_to_the_file\abc.json", mode)
```

Comment: `MPI_File_open()` is a collective operation and has hence to be invoked by all the members of the communicator. In this case, you likely want to use `MPI_COMM_SELF`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet i have just added the file opening mode i didn't change anything